# Android: Huawei M3 crashing on Chromecast initialization

Tags: android, chromecast, huawei-mobile-services

I have a customer w/ a Huawei M3 tablet that crashes on this line of code

```
mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(appContext)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbae.zzby (Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbae.zza (Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.<init> (Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance (Unknown Source)
```

He's on the latest Chromecast CAF library 15.0.0, but issues were occurring even on 12.0.1.

It could be device specific but I'm not sure. I haven't seen this happen with any other devices. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Update: Looks like alot of huawei devices are crashing. Found this on issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65359941 Seems like an ongoing issue.

Comment: Can you share what error have you encountered using a specific device?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the customer was opted in to the beta for Google Play Services and that was crashing the device. He installed the production one and it's working fine now.

Update: Even though this fix work for this customer. Alot of huawei devices are crashing. Found this issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65359941
Seems like an ongoing issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @mco says it's a known issue,not only huawei but with meizu phones too.
By now i'm catching the exception on chromecast initialization.

**The user fix is to delete google play services app data.**